# Problema con valores en Cookies PHP

Tags: php

Estoy creando unas Cookies desde PHP, y deseo aplicar valores por default

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'example.com');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', time() + 10000);
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/');
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', true);

session_set_cookie_params(time() + 10000, '/', 'example.com', true, true);
```

Pero cuando creo las Cookies

```
setcookie('X-Powered-By', 'PHP', time() + 1000, '/', 'example.com', true, true);
setcookie('X-App', 'APP');
```

La Cookie `X-App` no se crea con los valores establecidos en los `ini_set`

Probe en un servidor PHP 8 y local en PHP 7.3 y en ninguno funciono :(

Comment: Esos `ini_set()` afectan solo a la _cookie_ de sesión, para el resto, debes especificar todos los parámetros, tal como hiciste con `X-Powered-By`. Si tienes dudas, revisa la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) para ver los valores por defecto que se aplica a los parámetros cuando no los proporcionas.

Comment: Hay alguna forma, de establecer esos valores por defecto, aun en las Cookies que no son de sesión?

Answer (score 0):

Los valores por defecto de [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) son especificados en la definición de cada parámetro y no pueden modificarse "por fuera". En todo caso, podrías crear tu propia función para crear cookies con tus propios valores para cada parámetro que no se proporcione:

```
function myCookie(
    $name,
    $value = "",
    // A partir de aquí, estableces tus propios valores
    $expires = 10000,          // Se agregará a time()
    $path = "/",
    $domain = "example.com",
    $secure = true,
    $httponly = true
) {
    // Estableces la cookie con la función interna de PHP
    return setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
}
```

Cada que quieras crear una cookie con tus opciones por defecto, solo ejecutas tu función:

```
myCookie('X-App', 'APP');
```